# Training DNNRegressor with 2D labels

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, regression

I'm trying to learn a DDNRegressor with 2D labels:

```
estimator = tf.estimator.DNNRegressor(
    hidden_units=[10,10],
    feature_columns=feature_columns, 
    label_dimension=2
)

def train_input_fn():
    return tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(
        x = train_df,
        y = train_df[["coord_x", "coord_y"]],
        batch_size=100,
        num_epochs=1000,
        shuffle=True
    )

estimator.train(input_fn=train_input_fn())
```

but I stuck error:

> TypeError: Failed to convert object of type < class 'dict' > to Tensor. Contents: {'coord_x': < tf.Tensor 'random_shuffle_queue_DequeueUpTo:9' shape=(?,) dtype=float64 >, 'coord_y': < tf.Tensor 'random_shuffle_queue_DequeueUpTo:10' shape=(?,) dtype=float64 >}. Consider casting elements to a supported type.

What is correct way to pass 2D labels from Pandas DataFrame to `tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn`?

Thanks

Comment: does your input DF contains all numbers? DL libraries expects numerical inputs

Comment: @rock321987 Yes, there are only numbers in my DataFrame.

Comment: As per the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/inputs/pandas_input_fn) an error will be raised if **if x already contains a column with the same name as y, or if the indexes of x and y don't match**. But the error seems to be of data type.

Comment: @rock321987 I've try to exclude columns by defining names in `x`, but error still the same. Names of `x` and `y` have no intersection I am sure.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, but I'm not completely satisfied with it. Still looking for right way using `tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn`.

```
    def train_input_fn():
        features = {
            "rssi_x1": train_df["rssi_x1"].values.tolist(),
            "rssi_x2": train_df["rssi_x2"].values.tolist(),
            "rssi_y1": train_df["rssi_y1"].values.tolist(),
            "rssi_y2": train_df["rssi_y2"].values.tolist()
        }
        labels = train_df[["coord_x", "coord_y"]].values.tolist()

        dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(features), labels))
        dataset = dataset.shuffle(1000).repeat().batch(100)
        return dataset   

    estimator.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=90000)
```